# Create a Custom Waiting Room

Tags: android, google-play-games

i want to replace the default built-in waiting room with my own UI how can i do that ?

```
mRealTimeMultiplayerClient.getWaitingRoomIntent(room, MIN_PLAYERS)
            .addOnSuccessListener(new OnSuccessListener<Intent>() {
                @Override
                public void onSuccess(Intent intent) {
                    // show waiting room UI
                    startActivityForResult(intent, RC_WAITING_ROOM);
                }
            })
            .addOnFailureListener(createFailureListener("There was a problem getting the waiting room!"));
```